# Define different interfaces in different .svc files?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

```
I have two different Interface service that I'm using 
    1. IService1
    2. IService2

I define two files 
    1. IService1.cs   => that hold the Interface of IService1 
    2. IService2.cs   => that hold the Interface of IService2

I also define two different .cvs 
    1. IService1.cvs=> that hold the Interface of IService1 
    2. IService2.cvs=> that hold the Interface of IService2
```

Is OK to have this files struct or its better to have all the contract interface in one file and have one .cvs file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is .svc file.

If you have two .svc files you are exposing two different services (two classes) where each has single endpoint, its own WSDL and its own behavior (like security, throttling, etc.).

If you have one .svc file the service must implement both interfaces (one class) and it will have two different endpoints described in the same WSDL with single service behavior.

I will skip the part where you manually modify .svc files to point to the same class because it has no real benefit and it will make things even more complicated (configuration is per service class not per .svc file).

So it really depends on what requirements do you have?

Comment: Lets say that i want to expose the IService1 to basicHttpBinding and IService2 only to NamedPipeBinding - do i need to define them both in the same Services or need to define two Services in the config file ?

Comment: I would probably expose each on separate .svc because NamedPipes in WCF are not accessible from other machines and because of that the endpoint should not be in WSDL exposed to remote clients.

Comment: And to define those two endpoint ( pipe and basiehttp ) i can do it in the same service or i need to do it in different services in the config file ?

Comment: If each contract is implemented by different class you must have two service configurations in the config file. The configuration is applied by service name defined in `service` element. The name is by default the name of the class.

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

If the implementation of `IService1` and `IService2` are in the same class:

```
public class MyService : IService1, IService2
{
  ...
}
```

Then **one .svc file** and you need **two endpoints**.

If they are in separate classes:

```
public class MyService1 : IService1
{
  ...
}

public class MyService2 : IService2
{
  ...
}
```

Then **two .svc files**.